# How to use SUMIFS on several lines, using dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to sum values using sumifs but I am getting an error. Went throught several website but I guess I don't have a good understanding of how SUMIF works.
Right now I have a [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN6qA.png) with a registry date(C), a price per weeek(G) and a end date(D).

I would want to calculate the earning every week.
So I created another [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvF1A.png) with every week of the year.

```
=SUMIFS(Clients!G2:G;A5;>=Clients!C2:C;A5;<=Clients!D2:D)
```

I am not using coma as a separator as my google sheet is not in english.

I am trying to sum the incomes if the date on the second sheet is between the starting date and the end date. But I keep getting errors and I don't really unerstand why.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found an formula which look to be working.

```
=SUMIFS(Clients!G2:G;Clients!C2:C;"<="&A5;Clients!D2:D;">="&A5)
```

I guess that it was not working because I was letting A5 to incremente.
Problem solved.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Find out more [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en-GB) on Google's post about `=SUMIFS()`.

---

### Sample usage

- `SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, ">20")`
- `SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, ">20", C1:C10, "<30")`
- `SUMIFS(C1:C100, E1:E100, "Yes")`

---

### Syntax

> `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, criterion2, ...])`

- `sum_range` – The range to be summed.
- `criteria_range1` – The range to be checked against criterion1.
- `criterion1` – The pattern or test to apply to criteria_range1.
- `criteria_range2, criterion2, …` ***(OPTIONAL)*** – Additional ranges and criteria to be checked.